# Looping not activating in webpage

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Im fairly new to javascript and ive been trying to implement a small function on my site.

Ive wanted to periodically check for a particular variable and validate it.

Code:
Sorry for the poorly written format. Im quite new to this.

```
function Validate(){

    if (RequestedDate == undefined){

    }else if(RequestedDate > d){
    window.alert("Please select a date 3 days after the current date" + " Current Date : " + $('input.ecwid-productBrowser-details-optionDateField').val() );
    $('input.ecwid-productBrowser-details-optionDateField').val(null);
    setTimeout(Validate(), 2000);
    }
    }
window.alert("The validate function has executed atleast once");
})
</script>
```

Comment: `setInterval` and `setTimeout` are two different things

Comment: Hi,Would calling the function from the function itself, with a timeout not act in the same way ? we used to do it like that in python if I'm not wrong. with the while, delay, and break methods. again, sorry if I didn't get you. I'm pretty new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to execute the function at regular interval , you need to use [**setInterval**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) instead of `setTimeout`

Also note you are putting this asynchronous function inside the function itself, instead you need to put it outside it.

Also note the structure of `setInterval`

```
var intervalID = window.setInterval(func, delay[, param1, param2, ...]);
var intervalID = window.setInterval(code, delay);
```

You can put all your code inside `func` or else when it is callback you dont need `(` & `)`

```
function Validate() {

  if (RequestedDate == undefined) {

  } else if (RequestedDate > d) {
    window.alert("Please select a date 3 days after the current date" + " Current Date : " + $('input.ecwid-productBrowser-details-optionDateField').val());
    $('input.ecwid-productBrowser-details-optionDateField').val(null);

  }
  window.alert("The validate function has executed atleast once");
}
setInterval(Validate, 2000);
```